# print first row of one file in front of each row of second file

Tags: awk, sed

fileA

```
abc
```

fileB

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Expected output

```
abc 1
abc 2
abc 3
abc 4
abc 5
```

paste fileA fileB

my output like this

abc 1
       2
       3
       4
       5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you help us by editing your post to include any code you've already tried, please?

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a=$0;next} {print a,$0}' fileA fileB
abc 1
abc 2
abc 3
abc 4
abc 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed 's/^/'$(sed 1q fileA)' /' fileB
```

Insert the first line from fileA into the front of all lines in fileB.

Alternative using parallel:

```
parallel echo :::: <(head -1 fileA) fileB
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this way

this is for more than one column(3 in this case)

```
paste fileA fileB > file

awk 'NF==3 {a =$1;b=$3; print; next} {print a,$0}' file
```